# Excel VBA - Match 2 Columns and Delete duplicates on 2 sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Bit of a tricky problem here, I think. Or I'm missing that one function that will simplify it all :)

I have a spreadsheet with 2 sheets. Jan and Feb. I only care about columns 1 and 2 for the comparison. Here are examples of what I need to happen.

```
 --- Jan ---
results       Date/Time     column 3    column 4
test          Date/Time1    column 3    column 4
another_row   Date/Time     column 3    column 4

 --- Feb ---
test          Date/Time1    column 3    column 4
test          Date/Time2    column 3    column 4
test          Date/Time3    column 3    column 4
another_row   Date/Time2    column 3    column 4
results       Date/Time2    column 3    column 4
```

Output expected - Duplicates deleted, but the Feb version of the singular columns remain

```
test          Date/Time1    column 3    column 4
another_row   Date/Time2    column 3    column 4
results       Date/Time2    column 3    column 4
```

Feb will contain the exact same entry above plus 24 other duplicate rows with 'test' as column 1 and a different Date/Time for column 2.

I want to only keep the row values that are common between the two sheets. So the row in Jan is the one I want to keep in Feb, while deleting the 24 others.

So, for each row in the Jan sheet I need to search for the values of column 1 for a match in sheet Feb and if there is a match, compare column 2. If both are matching, I want to keep it. If not, delete it.

One other caveat, there are not duplicates of each value. So I only want to perform this removal if there are duplicates at all. Any unique, singular values, I want to keep. They may have different column 2 (time/date) but if the column 1 value is singular, it should stay.

Can this be done in VBA?

Here's my attempt to just find and delete the duplicates. I haven't even gotten to the unique value situation yet. This may not be my best approach, but it's my latest one. I attempted to set a flag to true/false and then if either flag was False, it should be deleted. Like I said, this doesn't handle my unique value requirement. But I was hoping to at least have it delete the 24 duplicates and keep the 1 value I need.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Dim nameBool As Boolean
Dim originatedBool As Boolean
Dim rDel As Range

Sheets("Jan").Select
lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lRow2 = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A2").Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

    For Each cell In Range("A2:A" & lRow) 'Assuming you have a 1 row header
    If cell.Value = Sheets("Feb").Cells(cell.Row, "A") Then
        'Sheets("Feb").Cells(cell.Row, "A").ClearContents
        nameBool = True
    Else
        nameBool = False
    End If

Next cell

For Each cell2 In Range("B2:B" & lRow2)
    If cell2.Value = Sheets("Feb").Cells(cell2.Row, "B") Then
        originatedBool = True
    Else
        originatedBool = False
    End If

Next cell2

If nameBool = False Or originatedBool = False Then
    'Debug.Print "Deleted"

End If

'rDel.EntireRow.Delete

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not following you completely (more complete examples of data input and desired output would help), but could you not just combine the two tables and then use `Remove Duplicates`

Comment: See below. I couldn't tell if you want to delete the row proper, or delete the contents. I can add that piece below if you specify, but the logic below should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it without endless loops, simply let the "excel formulas" calculate everything you need like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()
  Dim cal As Variant, i As Long, delRng As Range, LR_Cnt As Long, shtKeep As String, shtDel As String

  shtKeep = "Sheet1"
  shtDel = "Sheet2"

  LR_Cnt = Sheets(shtDel).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  cal = Evaluate("IF(COUNTIFS('" & shtKeep & "'!A:A,'" & shtDel & "'!A2:A" & LR_Cnt & ",'" & shtKeep & "'!B:B,""<>""&'" & shtDel & "'!B2:B" & LR_Cnt & "),ROW(2:" & LR_Cnt & "))")
  LR_Cnt = Application.Count(cal)

  If LR_Cnt > 0 Then
    Set delRng = Sheets(shtDel).Rows(Application.Min(cal))

    If LR_Cnt > 1 Then
      For i = 2 To LR_Cnt
        Set delRng = Union(delRng, Sheets(shtDel).Rows(Application.Small(cal, i)))
      Next
    End If

    delRng.EntireRow.Delete
  End If
End Sub
```

the `COUNTIFS` will output an array which holds all row-numbers for the `shtDel` with an match in `shtKeep` column A but no match in column B. Just keep in mind: I assumed there are no doubles in column A for `shtKeep` with different values in column B. In that case, the `cal` line needs to be changed from

```
cal = Evaluate("IF(COUNTIFS('" & shtKeep & "'!A:A,'" & shtDel & "'!A2:A" & LR_Cnt & ",'" & shtKeep & "'!B:B,""<>""&'" & shtDel & "'!B2:B" & LR_Cnt & "),ROW(2:" & LR_Cnt & "))")
```

to

```
cal = Evaluate("IF(COUNTIFS('" & shtKeep & "'!A:A,'" & shtDel & "'!A2:A" & LR_Cnt & ",'" & shtKeep & "'!B:B,""<>""&'" & shtDel & "'!B2:B" & LR_Cnt & ")*(COUNTIFS('" & shtKeep & "'!A:A,'" & shtDel & "'!A2:A" & LR_Cnt & ",'" & shtKeep & "'!B:B,'" & shtDel & "'!B2:B" & LR_Cnt & ")=0),ROW(2:" & LR_Cnt & "))")
```

While the second formula would work in both cases, it may take longer to calculate (depends on the count of rows in `shtDel` which are to be checked).

The only time you need to loop is when you go for all the rows which are to delete. But this is only to collect the numbers so you can delete all rows in one step to be faster ;)

If you have any questions, just ask.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you so much. I did end up using the second formula as there are duplicates in column A with different values in column B. But this works like a dream. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would nest loops like the below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim cell2 As Range
Dim nameBool As Boolean
Dim originatedBool As Boolean
Dim rDel As Range

with Sheets("Jan")
   lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   lRow2 = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
end with

   For Each cell In sheets("Jan").Range("A2:A" & lRow) 'Assuming you have a 1 row header
      for each cell2 in sheets("Feb").range("A2:A" & lrow2)
        If cell.Value = cell2.value then
           If cell.offset(0,1) = cell2.offset(0,1) then
               'keep
               exit for
           Else
               'delete
               exit for
           End If
        End If
      Next cell2
   Next cell
End Sub
```