# Excel formula or macro that will exclude values in a list that are present in another, expanding, list on the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, list, excel-formula, scheduler

I have one "master" list of addresses and an origin address. A macro (which I will post below) runs a google maps api which fetches all of the travel times between the origin and the addresses and then takes the address with the lowest travel time and pastes the address into a new "location order" list and then makes it the new origin. I then repeat the macro so it fetches the travel times between the new origin address and the remaining addresses.

What I am trying to do is have it so any address that has been an origin and thus added to the location order list would be excluded from the "master" list of addresses so they are not double counted.

Here is a screenshot of the distance/duration VBA, I did not make it but slightly edited it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mBaf.jpg

I have tried using IF and VLOOKUP commands but get stuck with #VALUE

Comment: Can you post the functions that you have tried ? exact functions strings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - Match 2 Columns and Delete duplicates on 2 sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38020613/excel-vba-match-2-columns-and-delete-duplicates-on-2-sheets)

Comment: Sorry I misspoke, I am getting #VALUE as my answers, here is one example:
=IF(VLOOKUP('Daily Schedule Data Parser'!B6,G18:G37,1,0),"Done",'Daily Schedule Data Parser'!B6)
Where G18:G37 is the range/list of addresses that have been used as the origin